# Event Handling between parent and child page in polymer 1.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I have a parent polymer element called parent-page and a child element called child-page.

parent-page calls child page and passes an array with it. for e.g, in parent page:

```
<child-page items={{itemsArray}}></child-page>
```

Now, on the basis of certain activity child page fires an event with a new array.

eg, in child page:

```
this.fire('eventPerformed', newArray);
```

This array is being listened by the parent page and received with expected values.
Now, I want to pass that new array to the child page such that the child-page is rendered according to the new array.

How to achieve it?

Edit: my child page looks like this.

```html
<dom-module id="child-page">

<style>
 
</style>

<template>
 
 <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{itemArray}}" as="fooditem">
       
  <div class="horizontal layout">
   <div>{{fooditem.quantity}}</div>
   <div>{{fooditem.name}}</div>
  </div>
 
 </template>
 <paper-button on-click"changeArray"> ChangeArray</paper-button>
 
</template>
 
<script type="text/javascript">

 Polymer({
  is:'child-page',
  properties:{
   itemArray:Array 
   },
  changeArray:function(){
   this.itemArray=<<Some new Array>>
             this.fire('eventPerformed',newArray);


  }
 });

</script>

</dom-module>
```

Is there any way I can call the template repeat with the new array in the same child page? Or do I  have to fire an event to the parent-page and call the child page again? How to achieve it either way?

Comment: But the child page already has that data, no?

Comment: Ok, you mean, I shoud not fire the event? Then how can i re render the same page based on the changed array?

Comment: if you have the data (`newArray`) why aren't you simply updating your properties?

Comment: Yea, it's a bit strange you would fire an event to the parent, only to have it reinform the child-page of the updated array. The child-page already knows about this. If you want the dom-repeat to re-render, try: `this.slice('itemArray', itemArray);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `child-page` re-renders its `template is="dom-repeat" items="[[itemArray]]"` automatically whenever its `itemArray` property was updated.

Just add `notify: true` to the `itemArray` property in `child-page` to enable two-way-binding with the `parent-page` element. Then the `parent-page` is also notified whenever the `item-array` of `child-page` has changed (see the [Polymer documentation on this topic](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#notify)).

Here is a small complete example:

```
<dom-module id="child-page">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[itemArray]]">
      <div>[[item]]</div>
    </template>
    <div on-click="_changeArray">Change</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'child-page',
      properties: {
        itemArray: {type: Array, notify: true}
      },
      _changeArray: function() {
        this.itemArray = [4,5,6,7,8,9];
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="parent-page">
  <template>
    <span>Item count: </span><span>[[itemArray.length]]</span>
    <child-page item-array="{{itemArray}}"></child-page>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'parent-page',
      properties: {
        itemArray: {type: Array, value: [1,2,3]}
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>

<parent-page></parent-page>
```

Btw. note my usage of `{{...}}` and `[[...]]`. [Use curly braces for two-way bindings and square brackets for one-way bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-binding).

Comment: Beautifully explained. Thanks